# CountVectorizer as N-Gram presence and count feature

Tags: python, scikit-learn, natural-language

Scikit-learn has a CountVectorizer under feature_extraction which converts strings(or tokens) into numerical feature suitable for scikit-learn's Machine Learning Algorithms.
It has a parameter like : ngram_range : tuple (min_n, max_n).

If I use :

```
vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range = (1,2))
```

Will it incorporate **Unigram feature : presence and count, Bigram feature : presence and count**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, Check the below implementation

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np

keys = ['little inspiration', 'time', 'occasion', 'creativity', 'innovation']

text = ('Everyone needs a little inspiration from time to time')

cv1 = CountVectorizer(vocabulary = keys, ngram_range=(1, 2) )
data = cv1.fit_transform([text]).toarray()
vec1 = np.array(data)
print(vec1)
```

Output

> [[1 2 0 0 0]]